# Android post JSON

Tags: android

hy,
I'd like to insert a person into the database, so I have to post the name and firstname
here is json url http://localhost:8075/myproject/personne/new

I thought to use

```
Map map = new HashMap ();
map.put ("name", "aaaaa");
map.put ("firstname", "eee");
```

but , I do not know WHAT TO DO to post the variables in the server.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a server side page, for example `insert.php`.
Then make httppost from your android application to server side page("insert.php")

[here is an example about connect to remote database in android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have your server up and running (so it's already accepting and handling post requests). Please also use an IDE that manages the imports automatically, I just added them for reference.

Following code is copy/paste from one of my projects and untested (please also excuse invalid references I might have missed).

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

private Response execute(String jsonData) {
    String url = "http://localhost:8075/myproject/personne/new";

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonData));

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        return parseResponse(response);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported encoding in JSON data", e);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Protocol based error", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
    }

    return null;
}

private Response pushPerson(Person person) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("firstname", person.firstname);
        json.put("lastname", person.lastname);;

        return execute(json.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error pushing person", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see there's no need for a HashMap, the JSONObject is what you are looking for. The `Response` can be nearly anything, that's up to you. "Normally" you would return the id of the newly created person.

There are plenty of tutorials out there. When I started I found each of them just by using a search engine. Please also always take a look at [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).